# How to determine the number of set values or non-set values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have the following function:

```
public function searchsubject(){

         $subject1 = Input::get('subject1');
         $subject2 = Input::get('subject2');
         $subject3 = Input::get('subject3');
         $subject4 = Input::get('subject4');

//if a single subject is chosen

return Redirect::route('home', array('subject1' => $subject1, 'subject2' => 
$subject2, 'subject' => $subject3, 'subject' => $subject4));

//if two subjects are chosen

return Redirect::route('hometwo', array('subject1' => $subject1, 'subject2' 
=> $subject2, 'subject' => $subject3, 'subject' => $subject4));

//if three subjects are chosen

return Redirect::route('homethree', array('subject1' => $subject1,   'subject2' =>
        $subject2, 'subject' => $subject3, 'subject' => $subject4));
```

My aim is to redirect the user to either of three urls.

1. url one if the user chooses one subject.
2. url two if the user chooses two subjects.
3. url three if the user chooses three subjects.

The question is how would I achieve this?

My idea is to bung all these values into an array and check how many of them have values and redirect accordingly but how is this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this, at first get the subjects:

```
$subjects = [];
$inputs = Input::all();
array_walk($inputs, function ($v, $k) use (&$subjects) {
    if(starts_with($k, 'subject')) {
        $subjects[$k] = $v;
    }
});
```

Now you have all `inputs/fields` that starts with `subject`, for example: `subject1`, `subject2` and so on. So now, just get the count of `$subjects` like:

```
$index = count($subjects);
```

Now you can use, for example:

```
// Keep this array pre-defined, could be a class property, if so then use $this->urls
$urls = ['zero', 'url-for-one-subject', 'url-for-two-subjects', 'url-for-three-subjects'];

// Redirect now using $urls[$index]
return Redirect::route($urls[$index)->with($subjects);
```

Comment: I get an error saying undefined function Redirect(). Im using laravel 4.2 btw

Comment: I thought I had cracked it but hadn't. the redirect im passing is `->with($subjects)` is an array. I need to pass it as a string so that I can use the value on another page. How do I do this?

Comment: if im using 4.2 is it the same?

Comment: I think I may have worded my question wrong. I actually need the value in the url so my url looks like this `home/1` not just `home`. Because i need to use the value to carry out another query on the page im redirecting to. Any tips I would appreciate otherwise i probably need to post another question

Comment: yeah. ive made a page called `url-for-one-subject` (example for one subject chosen). I have a function called home which accepts $subjects as a parameter. my route has a slug so that it can accept the parameter and so although it redirects it doesnt take the $subjects parameter. i essentially need it in the url

Comment: Actually, when you redirect using `with` method it flushes the inputs tto the session and to pass the inputs as route parameters you need to pass the inputs to the `route` method as the second argument as array.

Comment: Sorry mate you were right the first time. I had a silly bug. Finally done. @The Alpha